# Regarding an edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, editing

I suggested [this](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/379) edit on the [first version](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/revisions/760/1) of [this](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/760/qual-o-significado-de-oscultador-de-onde-vem) question.

The changes I suggested aren't properly identified by the system, so allow me to  spell out what I did. In addition to the tag (portugal) I also added the tag (português-europeu). (What's the difference between them anyway? Shouldn't they be synonymous?)

The edit was rejected because it "deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner".

Something in needs to be clarified in the above paragraph. What is it meant by the "goal of the post's owner"? Is it the actual goal intended by the OP or the goal suggested by the OP's choice of words? In practice this can be two very different things.

Note that the actual question is latent in the following sentence.

> "Gostaria de saber se ela é um termo técnico da programação, ou se em **Português Europeu** ela possui um significado específico".

The rest of the text in the question merely provides context, which is important, but doesn't define the question.

The purpose of this meta-question is for me to gain a better understanding of how the site is supposed to work by clarifying if I was wrong in suggesting that edit and if I was, exactly why is that the case?

In what way does adding the tags to a key term used the question deviates from the purported intent?

Comment: Yes, they should be synonymous.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the OP thought that his question was about the Portuguese language as a whole, as opposed to restricted to its use in Portugal.

He seems to have felt that he was not asking about "regionalisms", just about the meaning of the word. That it is used in Portugal would then be part of the answer, but *not of the question*.